# Can't get the right column value for a query containing max()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of data like :

```
Nm | item | type | value 
21 | 19   |  A   | 15
22 | 40   |  B   | 10
21 | 20   |  A   | 80 
32 | 40   |  C   | 40
```

I tried several queries and i always get : (for the record Nm = 21)

```
Nm | item | type | max(value) 
21 | 19   |  A   | 80
```

which is not what i want ,since the max value is from the item = 20

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: for the record Nm=21 : item should be 20 not 19

Comment: *"I tried several queries"* ... which are??  It's hard to help when you won't even show us how close you got, and it's impossible for us to discover your misunderstanding so we can help you learn.

Comment: See also [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find row which is having maximum value for particular nm. For that you need to lookup each nm and find maximum value in sub query and then compare that maximum value with main query.

**Query:**

```
select *
from item_table it_o
where it_o.value in 
(select max(value)
 from item_table it_i
 where it_i.nm=it_o.nm)
```

**Output:**

```
nm  item    type    value
22  40      B   10
21  20      A   80
32  40     C    40
```

Comment: Thanks that was the perfect query for the task, tho it took more than 5 minutes to fetch the result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select 
    * from table t1 where nm=21
    order by value desc
    limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Nm, item, type, value
  FROM ( SELECT Nm, MAX( value ) AS value 
          FROM YourTable 
         GROUP 
            BY Nm ) AS m
       NATURAL JOIN YourTable
 WHERE Nm = 21;
```

I've been asked to provide an explanation so here goes:

First, you need to find the maximum value (you haven't given a table name so I'm going to use `YourTable`):

```
SELECT MAX( value ) AS value
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE item = 21
```

Second, you want to project all attributes which requires joining the table expression above back to `YourTable` but we can't do that because we haven't projected the `Nm` attribute.

It's tempting to think we can simply project the attribute:

```
SELECT Nm, MAX( value ) AS value
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE item = 21
```

However, this makes SQL barf. To make SQL happy we must say which columns we are summarizing by (no matter how obvious it is!) using SQL's rather clunky `GROUP BY` syntax:

```
SELECT Nm, MAX( value ) AS value
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE item = 21
 GROUP
    BY Nm
```

Now we can join back to `YourTable` but again things aren't so simple:

```
SELECT Nm, item, type, value
  FROM ( SELECT Nm, MAX( value ) AS value 
          FROM YourTable 
         WHERE Nm = 21
         GROUP
            BY Nm )
       NATURAL JOIN YourTable;
```

Again, SQL barfs because we haven't given our derived table a name. Now you may be wondering, what is the point of giving it a name if we are using `NATURAL JOIN`, of which one of its advantages over, say, `INNER JOIN` is that we don't need range variables? Well, there is no point, it is not needed. However, the SQL Standards declared it is required. Therefore, we are forced to include a name, pointless though it is:

```
SELECT Nm, item, type, value
  FROM ( SELECT Nm, MAX( value ) AS value 
           FROM YourTable 
          WHERE Nm = 21
          GROUP
             BY Nm ) AS pointless_name
       NATURAL JOIN YourTable;
```

Note my SQL code above is different: one applies one's experience to change the structure of the query to make it generally more useful (sorry, I don't have an explanation beyond intuition for this!).

Comment: @TobySpeight: please give my explanation a read. Feedback is always welcome :)

Comment: That's now an outstanding answer!  Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `order by item desc` so max value come first then select only one row by doing `limit 1`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY VALUE DESC LIMIT 1
```

or you can select max id in subquery and select that id in main query (this query can return multiple rows)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE IN (SELECT MAX(VALUE) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Could you explain what both your queries produce in the event of a tie?  I don't think they are exactly equivalent.

Comment: It's not equivalent, first is preferred, second query will cause performance issue if you are working with huge data, because it's alternately two query one is sub and one is main

Comment: Am I right in saying that the first will only ever return 1 row, whereas the second will return all rows with the joint maximum value?  P.S. the question wants `MAX(value)`, so you could [edit] to maximize `value` rather than `item`/`id`.

Comment: i didn't get you, can you please explain :)

Comment: If there are two rows with `value` = `80`, then the first query will return one row (due to `LIMIT 1`); the second query will return two rows.  The question doesn't state which is required, so it's good practice to present both and explain why one or the other may be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM YourTable a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT nm
            , MAX(value) value
         FROM YourTable 
        GROUP  
           BY nm
     ) b
    ON b.nm = a.nm
   AND b.value = a.value
```

Comment: I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
select * from tablename where value = (SELECT  MAX(value) FROM tablename )
```

OR

```
select top 1 * from tablename order by value desc
```